# How can I prove this combinatorial identity $\sum_{j=0}^n j\binom{2n}{n+j}\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}=m\cdot4^{n-m}\cdot\binom{n}{m}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $n,m$ be non-negative integers.

How can one prove the following identity?

> $$\sum_{j=0}^n j\binom{2n}{n+j}\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}=m\cdot4^{n-m}\cdot\binom{n}{m}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, your thoughts, etc. so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem by using a well-known identitiy 
$\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}\binom{j}{m}=2^{n-m}\binom{n}{m}$.

Comment: I think there is some thing strange in your identiy , @nczksv how would we take cobination $ \dbinom{j}{m} $ for $j=0$ !

Comment: For $j < m$, $\binom{j}{m}=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let :

$$f_n:=\sum_{j=0}^n j\binom{2n}{n+j}\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}$$

$$g_n:=m\cdot4^{n-m}\cdot\binom{n}{m}$$

I will do the "snake-oil method" (it is hardcore I must admit, have fun...) as seen in the following (wonderful) reference :

http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

The idea, instead of showing $f_n=g_n$ for all $n$, take the associated formal power series $F$ and $G$ and show $F=G$, the snake oil method applies because $f_n$ is defined with a sum (I will invert the two sums and I will get the solution).

Then set :

$$ F(X):=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}f_nX^n\text{ and }G(X):=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}g_nX^n$$

You have  :

$$G(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}m\cdot4^{n-m}\cdot\binom{n}{m}X^n=\sum_{n=m}^{+\infty}m\cdot4^{n-m}\cdot\binom{n}{m}X^{n} $$

Then :

$$G(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}m\cdot4^{n}\cdot\binom{n+m}{m}X^{n+m}=mX^m\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\binom{n+m}{m}(4X)^n=m\frac{X^m}{(1-4X)^{m+1}} $$

On the other hand :

$$F(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=0}^n j\binom{2n}{n+j}\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}X^n=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=j}^{+\infty} j\binom{2n}{n+j}\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}X^n $$

$$F(X)=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}j\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}\sum_{n=j}^{+\infty} \binom{2n}{n+j}X^n=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}j\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}X^j\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \binom{2n+2j}{n+2j}X^n $$

And use the identity page 54 of the reference I have given to get :

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \binom{2n+2j}{n}X^n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4X}}(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4X}}{2X})^{2j}$$

$$F(X)=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}j\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}X^j\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4X}}(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4X}}{2X})^{2j}$$

Set $Y:=\sqrt{1-4X}$ then :

$$F(X)=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}j\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}\frac{1}{(4X)^j}\frac{1}{Y}(1-Y)^{2j}$$

But $4X=1-Y^2$ so :

$$F(X)=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}j\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}\frac{1}{(1-Y^2)^j}\frac{1}{Y}(1-Y)^{2j}$$

And then it reduces :

$$\frac{(1-Y)^{2j}}{(1-Y^2)^j} =\frac{(1-Y)^j}{(1+Y)^j}$$

$$F(X)=\frac{1}{Y}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}j\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}Z^j\text{ where } Z:=\frac{1-Y}{1+Y}$$

This looks like a usual formal power series now :

$$F(X)=\frac{1}{Y}\sum_{j=m}^{+\infty}j\binom{m+j-1}{2m-1}Z^j=\frac{Z^m}{Y}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}(j+m)\binom{2m+j-1}{2m-1}Z^j$$

$$F(X)=\frac{Z^m}{Y}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}(j+m)\binom{2m+j-1}{j}Z^j$$

Now

$$\sum_j \binom{2m+j-1}{j}Z^j=\frac{1}{(1-Z)^{2m}}$$

And

$$\sum_j j\binom{2m+j-1}{j}Z^j=ZD(\frac{1}{(1-Z)^{2m}})=\frac{2mZ}{(1-Z)^{2m+1}} $$

Hence :

$$F(X)=\frac{Z^m}{Y}(\frac{m}{(1-Z)^{2m}}+\frac{2mZ}{(1-Z)^{2m+1}})=\frac{1}{Y}(\frac{Z}{(1-Z)^2})^mm\frac{1+Z}{1-Z} $$

By an easy calculation :

$$\frac{Z}{(1-Z)^2}=\frac{X}{Y^2}\text{ and }  \frac{1+Z}{1-Z}=\frac{1}{Y}$$

$$F(X)=\frac{X^mm}{(Y^2)^{m+1}}=G(X)$$

Formal power series are equal, hence the coefficients must be. I don't know if there exists a "better" answer to this.

Comment: Wow! That's great.
It's a beautiful solution.
"Snake-oil method" is very useful.
Thanks for your answer.  @Clément Guérin

Comment: God bless formal power series.

Comment: Amazing! Can it also be proven using other methods?

Comment: @hypergeometric, I don't think so because I needed a really non-trivial formal power series to get to the result (the one with the squareroots), and I do think that it would be more complicated to find the combinatorial counterpart of this (but I can be wrong of course).

Comment: @ClémentGuérin - You're probably right. It would be nice if there is a rule of thumb to identify problems which can be solve manipulating binomial coefficients using identities and those which need other methods like considering the product of two binomials, or the snake-oil method you outlined.

Comment: @hypergeometric Consult my proof below for another method as you requested.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel - That's a rather impressive-looking proof!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we seek to verify that
$$\sum_{q=0}^n q {2n\choose n+q} {m+q-1\choose 2m-1}
= m \times 4^{n-m} \times {n\choose m}$$
where $n\ge m.$

We use the integrals
$${2n\choose n+q} = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n-q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+q+1}} \; dz.$$

and
$${m+q-1\choose 2m-1} = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{m+q-1}}{w^{2m}} \; dw.$$

Observe that the first integral is zero when $q\gt n$ so we may extend
$q$ to infinity.

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{m-1}}{w^{2m}}
\sum_{q\ge 0} q \frac{z^q (1+w)^q}{(1-z)^q}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{m-1}}{w^{2m}}
\frac{z(1+w)/(1-z)}{(1-z(1+w)/(1-z))^2}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n+1}} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{m-1}}{w^{2m}}
\frac{z(1+w)(1-z)}{(1-z-z(1+w))^2}
\; dw \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n}} 
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{m}}{w^{2m}}
\frac{1}{(1-2z-zw)^2}
\; dw \; dz.$$

We evaluate  the inner integral using  the negative of  the residue at
the pole at $w=(1-2z)/z,$ starting from
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+2}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{(1+w)^{m}}{w^{2m}}
\frac{1}{(w-(1-2z)/z)^2}
\; dw \; dz.$$

Differentiating we have
$$m\frac{(1+w)^{m-1}}{w^{2m}}
- 2m \frac{(1+w)^m}{w^{2m+1}}
= \left(w-2(1+w)\right) 
m\frac{(1+w)^{m-1}}{w^{2m+1}}
\\ = (-w-2) m\frac{(1+w)^{m-1}}{w^{2m+1}}.$$

The negative of this evaluated at $w=(1-2z)/z$ is
$$\frac{1}{z} \times m \times \frac{(1-z)^{m-1}}{z^{m-1}}
\times \frac{z^{2m+1}}{(1-2z)^{2m+1}}$$

which finally yields
$$\frac{m}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n-m+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-2z)^{2m+1}} \; dz.$$

We have that the  residues at zero, one and one half  sum to zero with
the first  one being the sum  we are trying to  compute.  Therefore we
evaluate these in turn. We will restore the front factor of $m$ at the
end.

For the residue at zero we have using the Cauchy product that
$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-m} {n-m+q\choose q} 
2^{n-m-q} {2m+n-m-q\choose n-m-q}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n-m} {n-m+q\choose q} 
2^{n-m-q} {m+n-q\choose 2m}.$$

For the residue at one we have that
$$\frac{(-1)^{n-m+1}}{(n-m)!}
\left(\frac{1}{z^{n-m+1}} \frac{1}{(1-2z)^{2m+1}}\right)^{(n-m)}
\\= \frac{(-1)^{n-m+1}}{(n-m)!} \sum_{q=0}^{n-m} {n-m\choose q} (-1)^q
\frac{(n-m+q)!}{(n-m)!\times z^{n-m+1+q}} 
\\ \times 2^{n-m-q} \frac{(2m+n-m-q)!}{(2m)!\times (1-2z)^{2m+1+n-m-q}}
\\= \frac{(-1)^{n-m+1} 2^{n-m}}{(n-m)!} 
\sum_{q=0}^{n-m} {n-m\choose q} (-1)^q
\frac{(n-m+q)!}{(n-m)!\times z^{n-m+1+q}} 
\\ \times 2^{-q} \frac{(m+n-q)!}{(2m)!\times (1-2z)^{m+1+n-q}}.$$

Evaluate this at one to get
$$2^{n-m} \sum_{q=0}^{n-m} {n-m+q\choose q}
2^{-q} {m+n-q\choose 2m}.$$

The residue at one evaluates to  the sum we seek just like the residue
at zero. This leaves the residue at one half, where we find
$$\frac{(-1)^{2m+1}}{(2m)!\times 2^{2m+1}}
\left(\frac{1}{z^{n-m+1}} \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}\right)^{(2m)}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{2m+1}}{(2m)!\times 2^{2m+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{2m} {2m\choose q} (-1)^q
\frac{(n-m+q)!}{(n-m)!\times z^{n-m+1+q}}
\\ \times \frac{(n-m+2m-q)!}{(n-m)! \times (1-z)^{n-m+1+2m-q}}
\\ = \frac{(-1)^{2m+1}}{(2m)!\times 2^{2m+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{2m} {2m\choose q} (-1)^q
\frac{(n-m+q)!}{(n-m)!\times z^{n-m+1+q}}
\\ \times \frac{(n+m-q)!}{(n-m)! \times (1-z)^{n+m+1-q}}.$$

Evaluate this at one half to get
$$-\frac{1}{2^{2m+1}}
\sum_{q=0}^{2m} {n-m+q\choose q} (-1)^q
2^{n-m+1+q} {n+m-q\choose 2m-q} 2^{n+m+1-q}
\\ = - 2^{2n-2m+1}
\sum_{q=0}^{2m} {n-m+q\choose q} (-1)^q {n+m-q\choose 2m-q}.$$

For this last sum use the integral
$${n+m-q\choose 2m-q} = {n+m-q\choose n-m} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{v^{2m-q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{n-m+1}} \; dv.$$

This controls the range so we can let $q$ go to infinity in the sum to
get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{v^{2m+1}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{n-m+1}}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {n-m+q\choose q} (-1)^q v^q \; dv
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{v^{2m+1}} \frac{1}{(1-v)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1+v)^{n-m+1}} \; dv
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{v^{2m+1}} \frac{1}{(1-v^2)^{n-m+1}} \; dv
= {n-m+m\choose m} = {n\choose m}.$$

We have shown that
$$2S - m\times 2\times 2^{2n-2m} \times {n\choose m} = 0$$
and hence may conclude that
$$S = m \times 4^{n-m} \times {n\choose m}.$$

**Remark.** If we want to do this properly we also need to verify that
the residue  at infinity of  the integral in  $w$ is zero.  Recall the
formula for the residue at infinity

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} h(z)
= \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\left[-\frac{1}{z^2} h\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right]$$

In the present case this becomes

$$-\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
\frac{1}{w^2} \frac{(1+1/w)^m}{1/w^{2m}} \frac{1}{(1-2z-z/w)^2}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
\frac{(1+1/w)^m}{1/w^{2m}} \frac{1}{(w(1-2z)-z)^2}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{w=0} 
(1+w)^m w^m \frac{1}{(w(1-2z)-z)^2}$$
which is zero by inspection.

The same procedure applied to the main integral yields

$$-\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
z^{n-m+1} \frac{1}{(1-1/z)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1-2/z)^{2m+1}}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
z^{n-m+1} \frac{z^{n-m+1}}{(z-1)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{z^{2m+1}}{(z-2)^{2m+1}}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}
z^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(z-1)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(z-2)^{2m+1}}$$
which is zero as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Remark.** This is my attempt to streamline the first proof. Not quite as simple as I had hoped but a start.

Suppose we seek to verify that
$$S = \sum_{q=0}^n q {2n\choose n+q} {m+q-1\choose 2m-1}
= m \times 4^{n-m} \times {n\choose m}$$
where $n\ge m.$

This is

$$\sum_{q=0}^n (n-q) {2n\choose q} {m+n-q-1\choose 2m-1}$$

which has two pieces. We use the integral

$${m+n-q-1\choose 2m-1} = {m+n-q-1\choose n-m-q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n-m-q+1}} (1+w)^{m+n-q-1}
\; dw.$$

Observe that this integral vanishes when  $q\gt n-m$ and we may extend
$q$ to $2n$. We get for the first piece

$$\frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n-m+1}} (1+w)^{m+n-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{2n} {2n\choose q} \frac{w^q}{(1+w)^q}\; dw
\\ = \frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n-m+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{n+1-m}} (1+2w)^{2n} \; dw.$$

The second piece is the negative of

$$\sum_{q=0}^n q {2n\choose q} {m+n-q-1\choose 2m-1}
= \sum_{q=1}^n q {2n\choose q} {m+n-q-1\choose 2m-1}
\\ = 2n \sum_{q=1}^n  {2n-1\choose q-1} {m+n-q-1\choose 2m-1}
= 2n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n-1\choose q} {m+n-q-2\choose 2m-1}
\\ = 2n \sum_{q=0}^{n-1} {2n-1\choose q} {m+n-q-2\choose n-m-q-1}.$$

This vanishes  through its  integral representation when  $q\gt n-m-1$
and we obtain

$$\frac{2n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n-m}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{n+1-m}} (1+2w)^{2n-1} \; dw.$$

Joining the two pieces we arrive at the single integral

$$\frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{w^{n-m+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{n+1-m}} (1+2w)^{2n-1} \; dw.$$

We know  the residues  at zero,  minus one and  infinity sum  to zero,
where the first  represents the queried sum. For the  residue at minus
one it is given by

$$\frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w+1|=\gamma} \frac{1}{w^{n-m+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{n+1-m}} (1+2w)^{2n-1} \; dw
\\ = \frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{1}{(v-1)^{n-m+1}} 
\frac{1}{v^{n+1-m}} (2v-1)^{2n-1} \; dv
\\ = -\frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{1}{(-v-1)^{n-m+1}} 
\frac{1}{(-v)^{n+1-m}} (-1-2v)^{2n-1} \; dv
\\ = \frac{n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\gamma} \frac{1}{(1+v)^{n-m+1}} 
\frac{1}{v^{n+1-m}} (1+2v)^{2n-1} \; dv.$$

We see that this residue also  represents the queried sum. This leaves
the residue at infinity which is

$$\mathrm{Res}_{w=\infty} \frac{1}{w^{n-m+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1+w)^{n+1-m}} (1+2w)^{2n-1}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2} w^{n-m+1} 
\frac{1}{(1+1/w)^{n+1-m}} (1+2/w)^{2n-1}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} w^{n-m-1} 
\frac{w^{n+1-m}}{(1+w)^{n+1-m}} \frac{(2+w)^{2n-1}}{w^{2n-1}}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^{2m-1}}
\frac{(2+w)^{2n-1}}{(1+w)^{n+1-m}}.$$

Extracting coefficients we find

$$-n \sum_{q=0}^{2m-2} {2n-1\choose 2m-2-q} 2^{2n-2m+1+q} 
(-1)^q {n-m+q\choose q}.$$

Introduce (this vanishes when $q\gt 2m-2$)

$${2n-1\choose 2m-2-q} = {2n-1\choose 2n+1-2m+q} 
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m-1-q}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2n-2m+2+q}}
\; dz$$

to get for the sum

$$-\frac{n 2^{2n-2m+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m-1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2n-2m+2}}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {n-m+q\choose q} 2^q (-1)^q \frac{z^q}{(1-z)^q}
\; dz
\\ = -\frac{n 2^{2n-2m+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m-1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2n-2m+2}}
\frac{1}{(1+2z/(1-z))^{n-m+1}}
\; dz
\\ = -\frac{n 2^{2n-2m+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m-1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{n-m+1}}
\; dz
\\ = -\frac{n 2^{2n-2m+1}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2m-1}}
\frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{n-m+1}}
\; dz
\\ = -n 2^{2n-2m+1} [z^{2m-2}] \frac{1}{(1-z^2)^{n-m+1}}
= -n 2^{2n-2m+1} [z^{m-1}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{n-m+1}}
\\ = -n 2^{2n-2m+1} {n-m+m-1\choose m-1}.$$

It follows that

$$2S -n 2^{2n-2m+1} {n-1\choose m-1} = 0
\quad\text{or}\quad
S = n 4^{n-m} \frac{m}{n} {n\choose m}$$

which yields

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
S = m \times 4^{n-m} \times {n\choose m}.}$$

as claimed.