# Show that sum of residues of $f(z)$ at it's poles is equal to $\frac{a_{n-1}}{b_n}$ where

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $f(z) = \frac{a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+.....+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}}{b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2+b_3z^3+.....+b_{n}z^{n}}$ $b_n \ne0$

Assuming zeroes of denominator to be simple, show that sum of residues of $f(z)$ at it's poles is equal to $\frac{a_{n-1}}{b_n}$

I approached the problem by writing denominator into factors say $(z-c_0)(z-c_1)(z-c_2)....(z-c_n)$

and then adding all residues using $\sum_{i=0}^n\lim \limits_{z\to c_n}{(z-c_n)f(z)}$

However I get stuck with different denominators of each term.

I found a solution where it generalises the formula by showing it true for couple of values of $n$. But this doesn't seem satisfactory enough. Is there a simple way to prove the desired result ?

I tried using Cauchy's integral formula but to no avail as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A  slightly different  approach which  can be  very useful  e.g.  when
applying the Egorychev  method is to use the fact  that for a rational
function  all  residues  including  the residue  at  infinity  sum  to
zero. (I  don't have a reference  ready at this time.)  The residue at
infinity is given by

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} f(z)
= - \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2} f(1/z).$$

This means the sum of the residues at the finite poles is given by

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2} f(1/z)$$

which in the present case yields

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
\frac{a_0+a_1/z+\cdots+a_{n-1}/z^{n-1}}{b_0+b_1/z+\cdots+b_n/z^n}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2}
\frac{a_0z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}z}{b_0z^n+b_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+b_n}
\\ = \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z}
\frac{a_0z^{n-1}+a_1z^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}}
{b_0z^n+b_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+b_n}.$$

This is

$$[z^0] \frac{a_0z^{n-1}+a_1z^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}}
{b_0z^n+b_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+b_n}$$

because the denominator is not zero at $z=0$ as per the problem
definition. With no pole at zero the constant coefficient can be
obtained from the ordinary Taylor series and is equal to

$$\left.\frac{a_0z^{n-1}+a_1z^{n-2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}}
{b_0z^n+b_1z^{n-1}+\cdots+b_n}\right|_{z=0} = \frac{a_{n-1}}{b_n}.$$

The rule that  residues sum to zero  may then be used in  a variety of
creative      ways,      for      example  at   this    [MSE      link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2318367/)   where  it   is
applied twice,  with the residue  at infinity vanishing in  the second
application as per the integral formula. The same technique is used at
this [MSE  link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254416/).
The Egorychev method with a non-zero residue at infinity is applied at
this [MSE limk III](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247818/)
(streamlined proof).

Answer (score 3):

The sum of residues is
$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C f(z)\,dz$$
where $C$ is a large enough circle with centre $0$. Let the radius $R\to\infty$.
$$\frac1{2\pi i}\int_C f(z)\,dz=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}
\frac{\cdots+R^{n-1}a_{n-1}e^{i(n-1)t}}{
\cdots+R^nb_ne^{int}}e^{it}R\,dt$$
etc.

Comment: How to solve the integral?

Comment: You only need its limit as $R\to\infty$ @AbhishekRana

Comment: Okay. So that means I can take lim R→∞ inside the integral. Taking R^n common from denominator will make all terms except last 0. Is this allowed? Can you please provide one or two more steps for clarity?

Comment: @AbhishekRana I do feel I have given enough hints, but the integrand converges to $a_{n-1}/b_n$ uniformly.

Comment: @AnginaSeng This saved me two pages of trying to prove via induction on $n$. Just beautiful